# How to change properties of Sencha Ext JS predefined UI elements

Tags: extjs

There is a UI class which is predefined by Sencha called `ui: 'navigation'` that sets my `Ext.tab.Panel` as a navigation menu in black color.

How can I override this UI to set the different colors and other properties? I cannot locate where is that SASS file defined.

Answer (score 1):

In `classic` it is in`Main.scss` file.
Path: `{YouProject}/classic/sass/src/view/main/Main.scss`
This is default:

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'navigation',
    $ui-tab-background-color: transparent,
    $ui-tab-background-color-over: #505050,
    ...
);
```

It is a `theme-mixin`, which, in case of tabpanel, is [extjs-panel-ui](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#css_mixin-extjs-panel-ui). If you want to override it copy/paste, change name(`$ui` variable) and other scss property values, then pass your ui name to tabpanel `ui` property. For example:

```
@include extjs-tab-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'my-own-ui',
    $ui-tab-background-color: #404040,
    $ui-tab-background-color-over: #303030,
    ...
);
```

All of this sass variables are described in this [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#css_mixin-extjs-tab-panel-ui)

More about [**Theme Mixins**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html#core_concepts-_-theming_-_creating_custom_component_uis)